# j_security_check returns 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, j-security-check, ibm-datapower

Im trying to do a Worklight form based authentication following this guide:

[Using WebSphere DataPower as a Security Gateway for Protecting Mobile Traffic](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038292).

Iim using a WebSphere Application Server  8.0.0.6, Worklight 6.0.0(EE)and when i tried to login using the app, the console on the navigator returns this:

POST http:// localhost :9081/probandoEldap/apps/services/j_security_check 500 (Internal Server Error) "

and the following message:

"com.ibm.websphere.servlet.session.UnauthorizedSessionRequestException: SESN0008E: An user authentication with anonymous has tried to access to a session which is property of user :defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/uid=wasadmin,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm.

IBM WebSphere Application Server"

Is there anything that I must config on my websphere to make it work?

Comment: How did you install Worklight? Why is the port number 9081? What did you implement in your Worklight project? How did you implement it? It feels like you're leaving out a large chunk of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem associated with wrong cookie. If you look into the j_security_check call you will see LTPA [most probably by the name LTPA2] cookies going with it. The cookie contains id of user 'wasadmin'. If you remove this cookie from request the problem will go away. Are you using local file based authentication?

- Ajitabh